# Dashboard that gets another workbooks charts and you can change the viewed chart with a combobox in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a dashboard that shows about 100 charts that I have in 7 other workbooks. 
My intention was to get the charts as images and be able to separate then with the click of a button and using combobox.

Something like this:

[image]

In the combobox should be something like "Chart 1" "Chart 2", and when I choose said chart, it shows the selected one.

As it turns out, this seems pretty complex. Anyone have an idea of where to start? I need a direction to start, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out to do it, using a simple vba code for the buttons and defined names and =CHOOSE(). It's more laborious than it is complex.